# SSL node.js -- Generate certificate on the fly

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, https, cryptography

I want to host HTTPS from node.js

BUT without involving external tooling like 'run this command' or 'install this certificate' or 'configure this here'.

I assume that involves:

- calculate some crypto from `Math.random()`,
- arrange into required binary format,
- feed to `https.createServer`.

Any clues how to do that?

Comment: You could always integrate some Let's encrypt utility in your code. Note that `Math.random()` is not secure enough to be used for cryptographic purposes.

Comment: It might work, but I'm afraid this part is essential: "BUT without involving external tooling"

Comment: Does an npm package constitute external tooling for you? If so, then this question is too broad and needs to go.

Comment: @artjom-b Do you have a solution with an npm package? Please share!

Comment: No, I don't have a solution. But I'm sure there is a short one.